# Calculate the sum of Market Capital by year and sector

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

Hello i have the following table. it has 6 New codes per yaer from 1 to 6. I need to calculate the market capital per year for the 6 New codes as
 `year 1832 New code 1 Sum 6502500 New Code 2 Sum = 236598 ....´

[image]

Comment: First plz try it by your self and if you face any problem then ask over here.

Answer (score 1):

From how I read your question you want 7 columns; `YEAR, SUM1, SUM2, SUM3, SUM4, SUM5, SUM6`

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 1 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 2 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 3 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 4 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 5 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE = 6 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE > 6 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM_ABOVE6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN NEWCODE < 1 THEN MARKETCAPITAL ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM_BELOW1
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  YEAR
```

I've added 2 extra fields as integrity checks.  This way you don't discard data, you always capture and aggregate it.  You may discard it later, after you've checked that both fields are always 0, for example.

Be careful, however, with that structure.  It's useful for presentation to a human being, but it is awful for further data processing.  If you're going to use this result within any other queries down-stream, just stick to the normalised structure that you already have and do a simple GROUP BY on it...

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  NEWCODE,
  SUM(MARKETCAPITAL)  AS MARKETCAPITAL
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  YEAR,
  NEWCODE
```

This normalised structure automatically adapts if/when you add another NEWCODE (No need for the SUM_ABOVE6 and SUM_BELOW0 as protection).  And it makes joining the data easier (The first form will condemn you to a life of CASE WHEN statements forever).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Year, Newcode, sum(MarketCapital) MarketCapital 
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Year, Newcode
```